# Save time to add CSS directly to the header or better to load via a path/ to the file?

Tags: css, performance

What I mean is, is it 'better' to place the CSS directly into the header or is the time saving negligible?

Thanks for all replies.

Comment: Define "better". If you put the CSS on the HTML, the HTML will have a bigger size and the same CSS will be sent on every request but you save one request to get the CSS (requests have expensive). If you use a separated file, you have an extra request, but you can use caching. The actual performance benefit will depend on a lot of things, there's no right answer. Also, read SO guidelines, this question does not belong to SO.

Answer (score 0):

People often actually do something like this. The technique is called critical css (https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/08/understanding-critical-css/). The idea is that your most important or above the fold css can go in a style tag served along with the page and the rest can be loaded in through a css file. I guess if you have a ton of css though you'll need to separate out the styles you deem as needed before the rest.
Loading a css file also has its benefits, such as browser caching - so that can be advantageous as well.